# Mouse not captured in Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I've installed the latest `Ubuntu Server` on Hyper-V (note it's Ubuntu server, not the desktop version, so it doesn't come with a UI by default;

Then using Hyper-V's "Virtual Machine Connection" app (not RDP, yet), I start/connect to Ubuntu, but the mouse remains uncaptured.

[image]

What do I have to do to get the mouse captured inside the VM window?

I looked around Hyper-V menus and settings, and still no clue. [Yes, I've also seen similar Q+A's on superuser but none that seem to apply]

**Edit:** To clarify, No I don't intend to install a GUI. I just want the mouse captured so I can copy + paste text within the terminal

Comment: Do you have a GUI installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: No I don't intend to install a GUI. I just want the mouse captured so I can copy + paste text within the terminal

Comment: Getting copy/paste in TTY mode will be quite the adventure. Clipboard sync even more so. May I instead suggest using SSH to interact with the virtual machine?

Comment: @Daniel, Yes that's the plan eventually. I will install something similar to Putty. but is it do-able, cutting+paste text within Putty ?

Comment: if your goal is to copy and paste, set up ssh on ubuntu, then install something like bitvise ssh client on Windows.  You're done, you'll have a much better experience than anything else you try.